# js-interop testing if javascript object has a property

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Is it possible to test if a javascript object contains a property?

I'm currently wrapping try/catch for each property I'd like to access. I dont think this is an efficient way to check if properties exist on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `try`-`catch` is the more efficient way to check that because there's only one exchange between Dart and Js.

---

An other way could be to handle your javascript object like a Dart [Map](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Map.html) with :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:js/js_wrapping.dart' as jsw;

main() {
  final myProxy = ...;
  Map<String, dynamic> myProxyAsMap = jsw.JsObjectToMapAdapter.cast(proxy);
  Iterable<String> keys = myProxyAsMap.keys;
}
```

But it is less efficient to check if `keys.contains("key")` than to use the `try`-`catch` way. Moreover if you intensively use this `keys` consider to copy the List with a `keys = myProxyAsMap.keys.toList()`. Actually `myProxyAsMap.keys` is still baked by an underlying js array. The `.toList()` will create a real Dart List and prevent Dart-js exchanges.